# SharePoint 365 List DateTime column needing no Time Zone affiliation

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, date-time, timezone

I have a SharePoint 365 custom list for my configuration team to receive requests from our internal business customers. There are date time fields for start date and end date of the configuration request. These fields are date & time format as even though the time is usually from 00:00 on the start date to 23:59 on the end date, there is the rare occurrence of a specific start or end time.

Recently, I had a customer from a different time zone enter a request with a specific start time. I discovered that they entered a request with a start time of 15:00, however it displayed as 12:00 to my team because the customer was in Eastern Time Zone and my team is in Pacific Time Zone. I need the sharepoint field to show the start time as the customer entered no matter what the time zone of the requester or our team.

Is there any way to ensure that the time part of the date time field does not get converted between time zones?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by updating the site's timezone under Site Settings -> Site Administration -> Regional Settings -> [Set your local timezone].

After this change, I refreshed the SP list page and the datetime showed up correctly.

Comment: So I would need to have each end user do that for their local timezone?